# Print text until set time runs out

Tags: java, timer, timertask

Here I have a program that prints text each 5 seconds. But I also need it to print
the data during those 5 seconds.

For example:

Make gesture 1

(here user is making gestures and I need to print all the data until 5 seconds pass)

Make gesture 2

(print all the data until 5 seconds pass)

and so on.

I tried adding a counter but it only prints data 5 times, and then again waits for 5 seconds to pass. But I want to print the data while those 5 seconds are passing.

```
int i = 1;
Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (i == 13) {
                    Thread.currentThread().stop();
                } else {
                    if (i % 2 != 0) {
                        System.out.println("Make gesture 1");
                        int currentSec = 0;
                        while (currentSec < 6) {
                            System.out.println("gesture data");
                            currentSec++;
                        }
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Make gesture 2");
                        int currentSec = 0;
                        while (currentSec < 6) {
                            System.out.println("gesture data");
                            currentSec++;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }, 0, 5000);
```

Is there a way to get the remaining time of TimerTask and use that time in the loop? If not how else can I do this?

**Output example:**

Make gesture 7

-6, -4, 1, -2, -3, 0, -1, 1, 7

3, -2, -4, 3, -1, -2, -1, -3, 7

7, 5, -3, 1, -1, -2, 0, 5, 7

0, -2, 0, 2, -1, -1, 3, 0, 7

0, -2, 0, 2, -1, -1, 3, 0, 7

-2, -3, 0, -4, -5, -3, -1, 1, 7

-2, -3, 0, -4, -5, -3, -1, 1, 7

-2, -3, 0, -4, -5, -3, -1, 1, 7

2, -1, 0, 2, -1, 0, -2, -1, 7

-1, 0, -2, -5, -2, 0, -1, 0, 7

1, 1, 0, -6, -2, -1, -1, -1, 7

-3, -1, -3, -1, 2, 0, 0, -3, 7

2, 2, 3, -2, 0, -1, -2, 3, 7

-3, -1, 5, 2, 2, 0, -1, -3, 7

-3, -1, 5, 2, 2, 0, -1, -3, 7

.
.
.

Make gesture 0:

4, -10, -10, 5, 21, 3, 10, 0, 0

12, 6, 15, 10, 13, -35, -1, 24, 0

-5, 9, 1, -2, -1, -6, -18, -9, 0

-5, 9, 1, -2, -1, -6, -18, -9, 0

-5, 9, 1, -2, -1, -6, -18, -9, 0

1, -14, -1, -3, -29, -6, 8, 2, 0

-22, -20, -8, -6, -7, -2, 3, -9, 0

1, 0, 1, 1, -5, -4, 4, 14, 0

0, 2, -5, 0, -4, 1, -30, -19, 0

0, 2, -6, -4, 6, 5, 2, 6, 0

-3, 1, -1, -3, 7, -2, -9, 1, 0

-3, 1, -1, -3, 7, -2, -9, 1, 0

-3, 1, -1, -3, 7, -2, -9, 1, 0

10, 21, -1, -1, -2, -4, -8, 2, 0

3, 5, 2, 4, -14, -38, -11, 0, 0

-3, 4, 9, 4, 55, 59, 27, 2, 0

-3, -12, -10, -3, -2, 0, 8, -5, 0

-3, -12, -10, -3, -2, 0, 8, -5, 0

-1, -11, -3, -2, 5, -6, -18, 3, 0

2, -9, 0, 2, 22, 13, 2, -4, 0

...

I managed to do this by using Thread inside if and else, but is there a better way to do it?

```
       if (i % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println("Make gesture 1");
            final long pastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println(data);
                        long currTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
                        if (currTime>= (pastTime + 5 * 1000)) {
                            Thread.currentThread().stop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            t1.start();
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: your question is not clear ..can u explain in detail?

Comment: I want to repeatedly print text during those 5 seconds intervals. 
The text would be numbers from user. 

Make gesture 1:
1,2,3,4,0,76,53,1
21,33,45,6,7,4,2,23
3,6,86,1,2,3,4,0
.
.
.
Make gesture 2:
different data
...

I managed to do this by adding a Thread inside if and else, but I thought maybe there's a way to do it by using the TimerTask data.